# Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImage?'

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift2

I am trying to run this code that will randomise a `UIImage`. But I am getting the following error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImage?`

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PersonsChoice: UIImageView!
var option = ["rock.png", "paper.png", "scissors.png"]

func chooseWinner(userChoice:Int){
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    PersonsChoice.image(option[randomNumber])

    if (randomNumber == 0 && userChoice == 1)
        || (randomNumber == 1 && userChoice == 2)
        || (randomNumber == 2 && userChoice == 0) {        
        resultLabel.text("You Win")
    } else if (userChoice == 0 && randomNumber == 1)
        || (userChoice == 1 && randomNumber == 2)
        || (userChoice == 2 && randomNumber == 0) {
        resultLabel.text("I Win!")
    } else {
        resultLabel.text("It's a draw!")
    }       
}
```

I am also getting the error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'`
for the `resultLabel.text`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the property `image` of an existing `UIImageView`, you need to assign it a new instance of `UIImage`:

```
PersonsChoice.image = UIImage(named: option[randomNumber])
```

Same thing for the `text` of a `UILabel`:

```
resultLabel.text = "It's a draw!"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Veducm.